# What does Enable flag do for Service

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-manifest

Officially, the `Enable` flag is for whether or not the `Service` can be instantiated by the system. But what does that mean in practice? Say I set `android:enabled="false”`. Does that mean START_STICKY will no longer work? How about START_REDELIVER_INTENT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the `Service` will not be created or run at all, regardless of what is returned from the `onStartCommand()` method, as it will never reach that point.

Just like for an `Activity`, `Service` instantiation is handled by the system, so when the documentation indicates that the system cannot instantiate a `Service` when `enabled` is `false`, it means that the `Service` just will not be run.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I would ever set this flag to false **in the manifest?**

Comment: You can enable/disable components registered in the manifest with the `PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting()` method, so if you want your `Service` disabled at installation, you'd set it to `false` in the manifest, and then enable it whenever you decide. This can be useful if, for example, your app offers a `Service` that can be bound by external apps, but you don't want the other apps to be able to do that until a certain condition is met; like registration verification, the completion of a necessary download, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Mike! Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a service to `android:enabled="false"` means that no one, not you, and not even the system or any 3rd party app (even if you set `android:exported="true"`), can start or bind to this service unless you programmatically enable it during certain lifecycles within your application.

It has its use-cases, for example, you might have a service within your app that you don't want any foreign app (be it a system app or a 3rd party app) to start (with `startService()`) or bind to (with `bindService()`) unless you allow so.

You might have a service that extends `HostApduService`, which lets your app to pretend to be an NFC card, and you would only want the system to run your service when an NFC reader device comes in proximity only during certain lifecycles within your app (like only when a specific Activity or Fragment is visible on the screen).

Here are some Kotlin extension functions for starting and stopping such services:

```
fun Context.runService() {
    val componentName = ComponentName(this, MyService::class.java)
    this.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
    this.startService(Intent(this, MyService::class.java))
}

fun Context.killService() {
    this.stopService(Intent(this, MyService::class.java))
    val componentName = ComponentName(this, MyService::class.java)
    this.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
}
```